# Varnish/Traffic-Server https caching support

Tags: proxy, cache, varnish

I know that Varnish does not cache's https connections.
Does apache traffic server caches https?

If no, is there a way to configure apache + Varnish + wordpress to cache https?

Answer (score 1):

Https cannot be cached in its encrypted form. What you need is to put an SSL termination proxy in front of varnish to decrypt the traffic and then let varnish cache the content.

You can use Apache to do the SSL termination by using mod_proxy and the directives [proxypass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [proxypassreverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) inside your Vhost configuration .

You can also check this two softwares:

- [Haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)
- [Hitch](https://github.com/varnish/hitch) from varnish-software that is designed to do this job

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to cache HTTPS traffic *while it is encrypted*, because the cache has no idea what is being requested, nor what is being returned in response.

The only way to do this is to terminate the TLS connection at or "before" the cache, perform the caching operation on the unencrypted traffic, and then (optionally) have the cache establish another TLS connection to the origin server to make the request.

Common technologies (but by no means the only options) to terminate TLS connections and forward them to a caching proxy include `stunnel`, `pound`, and `haproxy`.  Once you've terminated the TLS connection, you can use any caching proxy (including Varnish) to do the caching.